# C# project naming conventions

Tags: c#, refactoring, naming-conventions

I'm refactoring a C# application to pull the logic out to a class library so a GUI and a CLI can sit on top of it, I just can't think of what to name the projects themselves. (Note: This is about the projects themselves, not the folders inside of a project like what [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389458/c-sharp-project-folder-naming-conventions) references)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846805/naming-conventions-for-net-c-sharp-wpf-projects

Comment: You aren't going to get many answers with so few details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there are any accepted conventions around project names, but I typically see  patterns like the following:

- ProductName (contains business logic)
- ProductNameUI
- ProductNameCLI

Answer (score 0):

Projects should be named based on what they do or provide through the API. If it is a simple library for a view or presentation model, call the project UIDomain.